# Properly calculate cosine similarities for low memory on large datasets?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am following this tutorial here to just learn a bit about content recommenders: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/recommender-systems-python

but i ran into a `Memory Error` when running the "content based" part of the tutorial. Upon some reading I found that this has to do with just how large the dataset being used it. I couldn't really find an exact way for this specific case on how to run this with low memory, so instead i modified this a little bit to split the original dataframe up into 6 pieces, run this cosine similarity calculation for each split dataframe, merge together the results, then run this one last time to get a final result. here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import linear_kernel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

# Function that takes in movie title as input and outputs most similar movies
def get_recommendations(title, indices, cosine_sim, final=False):
    # Get the index of the movie that matches the title
    idx = indices[title]

    # Get the pairwsie similarity scores of all movies with that movie
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))

    # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    # Get the scores of the 10 most similar movies
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]

    # Get the movie indices
    movie_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    # Return the top 10 most similar movies
    if not final:
        return metadata.iloc[movie_indices, :]
    else:
        return metadata['title'].iloc[movie_indices]

# Load Movies Metadata
metadata = pd.read_csv('dataset/movies_metadata.csv', low_memory=False)

#Define a TF-IDF Vectorizer Object. Remove all english stop words such as 'the', 'a'
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

#Replace NaN with an empty string
metadata['overview'] = metadata['overview'].fillna('')

split_db = np.array_split(metadata, 6)

source_db = None
search_db = None
db_remove_idx = None
new_db_list = list()
for x, db in enumerate(split_db):
    search = db.loc[db['title'] == 'The Dark Knight Rises']
    if not search.empty:
        source_db = db
        new_db_list.append(source_db)
        search_db = search
        db_remove_idx = x
        break

split_db.pop(db_remove_idx)

for x, db in enumerate(split_db):
    new_db_list.append(db.append(search_db, ignore_index=True))

del(split_db)

refined_db = None

for db in new_db_list:
    small_db = db.reset_index()
    #Construct the required TF-IDF matrix by fitting and transforming the data
    tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(small_db['overview'])
    
    # Compute the cosine similarity matrix
    cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
    #cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
    
    #Construct a reverse map of indices and movie titles
    indices = pd.Series(small_db.index, index=small_db['title']).drop_duplicates()
    
    result = (get_recommendations('The Dark Knight Rises', indices, cosine_sim))
    if type(refined_db) != pd.core.frame.DataFrame:
        refined_db = result.append(search_db, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        refined_db = refined_db.append(result, ignore_index=True)

final_db = refined_db.reset_index()
#Construct the required TF-IDF matrix by fitting and transforming the data
tfidf_matrix = tfidf.fit_transform(final_db['overview'])

# Compute the cosine similarity matrix
cosine_sim = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)

#Construct a reverse map of indices and movie titles
indices = pd.Series(final_db.index, index=final_db['title']).drop_duplicates()

final_result = (get_recommendations('The Dark Knight Rises', indices, cosine_sim, final=True))
print(final_result)
```

i thought this would work, but the results are not even close to what is given in the tutorial:

```
11       Dracula: Dead and Loving It
13                             Nixon
12                             Balto
15                            Casino
20                        Get Shorty
18    Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls
14                  Cutthroat Island
16             Sense and Sensibility
19                       Money Train
17                        Four Rooms
Name: title, dtype: object
```

could anyone explain what i am doing wrong here? i figured since the dataset was too large by splitting it up, running this "cosine similarity" process as first a refinement, then using the resulting data and running the process again would give a similar result, but then why is the result i am getting so different than what is expected?

And this is the data i am using this against: https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset/data